# How to make Recycler View Reactive to SizeChange in MultiWindow/PIP?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, multi-window

I am make my app compatible to multi-window and PIP(Picture in Picture).

I have a Recycler View which is of Type GridLayout Holder having TextView and ImageView for each View Holder.

I am giving my Holder's dimension's in `DP`(just for info i.e it should resize based on new size of window) and by default the recyclerView in not handling the `onSizeChanged()` call. So I Created a customRecycler to handle `onSizeChanged()` call's. But i am not sure how to handle the size change of recyclerView as on Size Change i should re-render all View-holder also(just guessing).

```
class CustomRecyclerView : RecyclerView {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet) : super(context, attributeSet)

    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
       /*
         post {
          requestLayout()  // forcing relayout but this also doesn't work with or without post.
       }
       */
    }
}
```

If i am starting the app in Full screen and and then switching to PIP. then result is below.

**Expected Result:**
[image: Result 1]

**Issue:**
[image]

*The issue here that i understood is the Recycler View when the size is changed is not re-rendering/re-layouting the whole view the the size of the Viewholder holder in not updated when the size of the Application window is changed.*

What approach should i use to force recyclerView to adjust according to new screen size?